# In Tensorflow, how to pass more than one SparseTensor to sess.run()

Tags: tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I have a dataset which is very sparse, and due to memory constraints, I am forced to represent them in a sparse way. Thus, I am thinking of using `tf.sparse_placeholder` and `tf.SparseTensorValue`.

I need to pass to the computation graph, more than one `tf.SparseTensorValue`. However, I am getting the following error:
`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Here is a minimal code snippet that reproduces the aforementioned intention and error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.sparse_reduce_sum(x)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    indices = np.array([[3, 2, 0], [4, 5, 1]], dtype=np.int64)
    values = np.array([1.0, 2.0], dtype=np.float32)
    shape = np.array([7, 9, 2], dtype=np.int64)

    xs = list()
    xs.append(tf.SparseTensorValue(indices, values, shape))
    xs.append(tf.SparseTensorValue(indices, values, shape))

    print(sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: xs }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sparse_placeholder can only be fed one sparse tensor. If you want to feed more than one, you need to build a sparse tensor which corresponds to the stacked version of your original input tensors.

For example the following should work:

```
x0 = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32)
x1 = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32)
x = tf.sparse_concat(axis=0, sp_inputs=[x0, x1])
y = tf.sparse_reduce_sum(x)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  indices = np.array([[3, 2, 0], [4, 5, 1]], dtype=np.int64)
  values = np.array([1.0, 2.0], dtype=np.float32)
  shape = np.array([7, 9, 2], dtype=np.int64)

  sp = tf.SparseTensorValue(indices, values, shape)
  print(sess.run(y, feed_dict={x0: sp, x1: sp }))
```